# Golang: How to convert int to calculate into time.duration

Tags: go, time, casting, flags

I'm new to GoLang and at the moment at a loss why the compiler does not accept a particular line of code.

I've got this working example for creating a timeout when dialing:

```
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(*connAddress,
      grpc.WithInsecure(),
      grpc.WithBlock(),                  // will block till the connection is available
      grpc.WithTimeout(100*time.Second)) // times out after 100 seconds
```

Now the hardcoded 100 there is not nice, so I would like to make that a commandline variable via a flag, like so:

```
    connTimeout := flag.Int64("connection-timeout", 100, "give the timeout for dialing connection x")
...
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(*connAddress,
      grpc.WithInsecure(),
      grpc.WithBlock(),
      grpc.WithTimeout(*connTimeout*time.Second))
```

However this gives the following compilation error:

> mismatched types int64 and time.Duration

So apparently I can't use the int64 flag variable directly to calculate a duration but a number can?

Eventually I found a solution for using the flag variable by creating a variable related to time.Duration first:

```
var timeoutduration = time.Duration(*distributorTimeout) * time.Second
    // create distributor connection
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(*connAddress,
        grpc.WithBlock(),
        grpc.WithTimeout(timeoutduration))
```

The above seems to work as expected: the dialing is tried for as long as the commandline parameter given (default 100) and than throws a message that the connection could not be made. Good.

However: How come directly using the int64 flag-variable is not possible for calculating a time.Duration, in other words what is the difference for golang between the number 100 and the variable that contains the int64?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but consider using [`flag.Duration`](https://godoc.org/flag#Duration) instead of `flag.Int64`.

Comment: Hi @CeriseLimón Yes, thanks for the suggestion: those are the things I'm looking for as a Golang newby :) That saves referring to time.Duration indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grpc.WithTimeout(100*time.Second)` and `grpc.WithTimeout(*connTimeout*time.Second)` does not because of [assignability rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

the latter expression satisfies none of those, and the former satisfies the

- `x` is an untyped constant representable by a value of type `T`.

rule